# Android SDK Projector API

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy, projector

I have a Samsung Galaxy Beam smartphone. Galaxy Beam is integrated with a projector. I want to  use its projector for developing. As far as I know Samsung doesn't provide an API for developing. Does Android SDK has an api for this? or Is there any way to control its projector ?